# C to assembly MIPS-32

Tags: c, assembly, mips32

Is there any converter from C to assembly MIPS-32?
I need to make a project and it would be helpful some sort of compiler.
I've tried https://godbolt.org/ but it doesn't have any to mips 32 bits

Comment: That's called a compiler and yes, there is mips gcc on godbolt. You might have missed it, you can just type "mips" in the compiler selection search box.

Comment: You're incorrect, that website does have MIPS.  What it doesn't have MARS/QtSpim-simulator specific assembly.

Comment: @ErikEidt do u know any that has MARS especific?

Comment: Probably no one wants to make a MARS/QtPSIM C compiler b/c it would not be profitable, helping mostly only students trying to avoid learning MIPS assembly in their coursework; not exactly a lucrative market!

Comment: MIPS GCC with `-march=mips32` will compile for [MIPS32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64), the first update of the ISA after SGI spun it off as a separate company, MIPS Technologies, I think.  Later revisions of MIPS32 / MIPS64 can be targeted with options like `-march=mips32r6`.  By default MIPS GCC compiles for 32-bit mode of older MIPS I or MIPS II, or maybe MIPS III or something.

Comment: What is missing from a generic MIPS C compiler that you need for MARS/QTspim to work? The syscalls?